# Can the product of an increasing monotonic function and a strictly increasing monotonic function have turning points

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose $f:\Re \rightarrow [0,1]$ is an increasing monotonic function and $g:\Re \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a strictly increasing monotonic function.

For the product function $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$, will there exists a local maximum? If the gradient of $f$ and $g$ are different, I think there exists a turning point for $h$?

I am thinking if it is possible that $h$ can become a concave function, with a local maximum?

Previously, I misunderstood turning point to be a local maximum.

Comment: What is a 'turning point'?

Comment: $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$, no?

Comment: I guess you mean $h=fg$, not $h=gh$.  If $f\equiv 0$ then $h\equiv 0$; does $0$ have a "turning point"?  If $f\equiv 1$ then $h=g$; can $g$ have a "turning point"?

Comment: @JonasMeyer This means that it is not possible for $h$ to have a "turning point"?

Comment: @Michael: I still don't know what you mean by turning point.  "optimal point" Meaning a local max or min value?  No, the hypotheses imply that $h$ is increasing.  Meaning an inflection point?  Yes it is possible, e.g. because $f$ can be $1$ and $g$ can have an inflection point.  Meaning something else?  I don't know.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I mean to say that the optimal point is a local maximum. My mistake in confusing turning point to be local maximum

Comment: @Michael: $0\leq a\leq b$ and $0\leq c\leq d$ implies $ac\leq bd$. So $h$ is increasing.

Answer (score 2):

I guess `turning point` (German: *Wendepunkt*?) is `point of inflection` and you mean $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$. Then the answer is yes: Take 
$$f(x) \equiv 1, \quad g(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\arctan x}{\pi}$$
then both functions are $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$, $f$ is increasing monotonic,
$g$ is strictly increasing monotonic, $h''(0) = 0$ and $h'''(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: Great answer! Is there a set of conditions that need to be fulfilled in order to ensure $h$ has a point of inflection?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point, the German Wiki page has conditions without using the third derivative. And there is a sufficient condition on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications, I am sorry for mistaken turning point to be local maximum, which I was asking.